# Hiding a certain element called from an API

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

I'm calling images from an API - I want to exclude / not show an image with a certain 'ImageType' - called 'Logo'.

here's my snippet loading the images, I can't work out how to exclude the Logo type. Please can anyone point me in the right direction ?

**This is calling the images on the venue page:**

```
$morevenuedata = venuedetails($getmoreapidataurl);

foreach ($morevenuedata->AllImages as $image) {
    $venueimages[$i] = $image->Url;
    if ($image->ImageType == 'Main') {
        $venueimage = $image->Url;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

And here is where it's displayed on the page

```
<ul class="slides">
    <?php foreach ($morevenuedata->AllImages as $image) {
        echo "<li>";
        // echo "<a class='example-image-link' href='".$image->Url."' data-lightbox='exterior-set' >";
        echo "<img src='".$image->Url."' alt='".$image->Description."' class='img-slider'>";
        // echo "</a>";
        echo "</li>";
    } ?>
</ul>
```

Where would I go about excluding ImageType 'Logo' from displaying in the slideshow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for that type in the `foreach` loop, eg:

```
<ul class="slides">
<?php foreach ($morevenuedata->AllImages as $image) {
   if($image->ImageType === 'Logo') {
       continue;
   }
   echo "<li>";
   // echo "<a class='example-image-link' href='".$image->Url."' data-lightbox='exterior-set' >";
   echo "<img src='".$image->Url."' alt='".$image->Description."' class='img-slider'>";
   // echo "</a>";
   echo "</li>";
} ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to inspire.. You can try something like this.

```
$morevenuedata = venuedetails($getmoreapidataurl);

$imagesToReturn = [];

foreach ($morevenuedata->AllImages as $key => $image) {
    $venueimages[$key] = $image->Url;
    if ($image->ImageType == 'Main') {
        $venueimage = $image->Url;
        $imagesToReturn[] = $venueimage;
    }
}

return $imagesToReturn;
```